# Mistake of 401 comingled account

Tags: united-states, 401k

About 5 years ago the company I used to work for switched advisor's from Mass Mutual to Edward Jones, so employee accounts were rolled over.

During this process, 21 years of my funds were co-mingled with another employee's account.  Only the contributions I made thereafter went into the new 401 with Edward Jones.

I had inquired a few times about the balance, was told one thing or another, really didn't think much of it, thought I might be looking at statements wrong, never opened all of them to be truthful about it.

Two years ago I left the company to take a federal job.  For the past two years I have been trying to get straight answers about my balance and to roll it over to my federal 401.

I finally got sick and tired of the run around and basically threatened the CEO of my former company.  He gave me the Edward Jones number to call and said, by the way, your account has been co-mingled with other employee's (providing me her name) and we have been working on it for the past two years.

No one can tell me even the amount that should be mine.
No one ever contacted me upon discovery, only after I requested the roll over.
What can I do?

Comment: Is the other "cominglee" aware of the situation?

Comment: Not sure is she knows or not.  Like I said, the only reason I was informed was I wanted access for roll over.

Answer (score 11):

Sue them. This thing should have been resolved ASAP when it was discovered, and within weeks at most after the transfer. It will take some forensic accounting to separate the accounts after several years. You and her probably had different types of investments in different proportions, and tracking this down will take efforts which you shouldn't pay for. Talk to a qualified attorney ASAP.